# Selecting the Average of each night in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have data like this

```
+-----------------------+---------+
| DateTime              |  Value  |
+-----------------------+---------+
| 2015-08-18 19:36:42   |  22     |
| 2015-08-18 20:48:49   |  20     |
| 2015-08-18 21:48:49   |  19     |
| 2015-08-18 22:48:49   |  23     |
| 2015-08-18 23:48:49   |  20     |
| 2015-08-19 00:48:49   |  23     |
| 2015-08-19 01:48:49   |  21     |
| 2015-08-19 02:48:49   |  15     |
      ...                   ...
| 2015-08-19 22:30:16   |  21     |
| 2015-08-19 23:30:16   |  22     |
| 2015-08-20 00:30:16   |  25     |
| 2015-08-20 01:30:16   |  26     |
      ...                   ...
| 2015-08-20 22:30:16   |  19     |
| 2015-08-20 23:30:16   |  20     |
| 2015-08-21 00:30:16   |  21     |
| 2015-08-21 01:30:16   |  21     |
      ...                  ...
```

And I want to select average of each night where night start from current date at 06:00:00 and end next date at 06:00:00.
Like night from 2015-08-18 As '2015-08-18'
And I want the final results to look like below:

```
+---------------+---------+
| DateTime      | AvgValue|
+---------------+---------+
| 2015-08-18    |  22     |
| 2015-08-19    |  20     |
| 2015-08-20    |  19     |
| 2015-08-21    |  23     |
| 2015-08-22    |  20     | 
    ...            ..
```

I have went though many website, book and go though most tutorials but I can not figure a way on how to write this Query to perform this.

Can any one please help me with query to get the above results.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a query like this, although it may be slow:

```
select date(`DateTime` - interval 6 hour), avg(`Value`) as AvgValue
from   tblName
group by date(`DateTime` - interval 6 hour)
order by 1 asc
```

But I strongly recommend to add an additional column that stores only the night (without the time) the record belongs to and add an index to that column, so that query can be handled much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   if(hour(DateTime) >= 18, 
            date(date_add(Datetime, interval 1 day)), date(Datetime)) DateAct,     
         avg(`Value`) as AvgValue
from     yourTable
group by DateAct
order by 1;
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/KSB39578

Comment: This can't work. It will display each row individually because all of them will have a different time, so there is no grouping at all

Comment: I know ;) I'm just answering your comment.